# How to write a custom f1 loss function with weighted average for keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to do a multiclass classification in keras. Till now I am using  **categorical_crossentropy**
as the loss function. But since the metric required is **weighted-f1**, I am not sure if **categorical_crossentropy** is the best loss choice. I was trying to implement a weighted-f1 score in keras using **sklearn.metrics.f1_score**, but due to the problems in conversion between a tensor and a scalar, I am running into errors.

Something like this:

```
def f1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   return 1 - f1_score(np.argmax(y_true, axis=1), np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), average='weighted')
```

Followed by

```
 model.compile(loss=f1_loss, optimizer=opt)
```

How do I write this loss function in keras?

**Edit:**

Shape for **y_true and y_pred** is **(n_samples, n_classes)** in my case it is **(n_samples, 4)**

**y_true** and **y_pred** both are **tensors** so sklearn's f1_score cannot work directly on them. I need a function that **calculates weighted f1 on tensors**.

Comment: Please post the shapes for `y_true` and `y_pred`.

Comment: Shape is (n_samples, n_classes) in my case it was (n_samples, 4)

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric this is non weighted f1-loss implemented for 2 classes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The variables are self explained:

```
def f1_weighted(true, pred): #shapes (batch, 4)

    #for metrics include these two lines, for loss, don't include them
    #these are meant to round 'pred' to exactly zeros and ones
    #predLabels = K.argmax(pred, axis=-1)
    #pred = K.one_hot(predLabels, 4) 


    ground_positives = K.sum(true, axis=0) + K.epsilon()       # = TP + FN
    pred_positives = K.sum(pred, axis=0) + K.epsilon()         # = TP + FP
    true_positives = K.sum(true * pred, axis=0) + K.epsilon()  # = TP
        #all with shape (4,)
    
    precision = true_positives / pred_positives 
    recall = true_positives / ground_positives
        #both = 1 if ground_positives == 0 or pred_positives == 0
        #shape (4,)

    f1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall + K.epsilon())
        #still with shape (4,)

    weighted_f1 = f1 * ground_positives / K.sum(ground_positives) 
    weighted_f1 = K.sum(weighted_f1)

    
    return 1 - weighted_f1 #for metrics, return only 'weighted_f1'
```

**Important notes:**

This loss will work batchwise (as any Keras loss).

So if you are working with small batch sizes, the results will be unstable between each batch, and you may get a bad result. **Use big batch sizes**, enough to include a significant number of samples for all classes.

Since this loss collapses the batch size, you will not be able to use some Keras features that depend on the batch size, such as sample weights, for instance.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I am getting a weighted f1-score greater than 1,  using  your implementation

Comment: @learner, are you working with "binary" outputs AND targets, both with exactly the same shape?

Comment: @Daniel Moller I am working on a multi classification problem

Comment: @Daniel Moller : I am getting a nan validation loss with your implementation. Any clue ?

Comment: @johnnyp, no clue... I put the `K.epsilon()` there to avoid division by zero, so the nan may be coming from another part of the code. You must check everything to see where it appears. And you should check that you're working with "binary" outputs (range 0 to 1) and that the model outputs have the exact same shape as the targets (y_true and y_pred, same shape).

Comment: @Daniel Moller : I finally got it. I don't know why but sometimes at the beginning of an epoch K.sum(ground_positives)=0. So in f1_weighted I divide by K.sum(ground_positives) + K.epsilon() and this solves the issue. Thanks for the hint !

Comment: Great, @johnnyp . I didn't notice there was a missing epsilon in the average. I moved the epsilon to the very top, since it should be used everywhere, including the numerator of the average (if ground_positives are zero, you still want the average to work by multiplying everything by 1/4 instead of 0)